# Problem using Leaflet Map

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am trying to use a simple Leaflet Map, which gets its markers from a AJAX feed and I have got it working on a basic HTML page outside Drupal.

But when I try to use it from Drupal, only an empty (gray) map window presents itself.

I have tried to use it in a paragraph currently with the following simple contents:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<style>
    #testmap {
        height: 700px;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>

<h2>Map</h2>
<div id="testmap"></div>


<script>
    var mymap = L.map('testmap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
</script>
```

That is basically/exactly what Leaflet site suggests but it seems not to work in this context and I just don't understand why.

I need only this map on the site, so almost anything working would do... Only I don't seem to get anything working.

I know embedding the css and js-scripts to the paragraph itself is far from the perfect solution, but I just don't grasp, how to get anything using library tp work, I keep getting L is not defined, if addingthe js in the end of the body and if forcing it to the header, there comes another error about Drupal-function.

I could use IFrame with my already working implementation, but as it is in the bottom of my favorites I would prefer any other solution over it.

Could anybody help me?

With best regards

Hank

Comment: Try to figure out how to normally attach libraries in Drupal. You also should consider to only attach the library to this certain paragraph type. Next find out how to pass PHP variables to JS in Drupal. And then have the leaflet library be a dependency of your custom JS library where you do your magic. Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module and https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme specifically.

Comment: Ok, sorry. This was my first Leaflet-implementation and I had missed adding a layer onto map, really dumb *blush*. Thanks for the pointers regarding preprocess, I think I got it right